# Windows 10 - Force OneNote to Use Wifi over Ethernet

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet

Microsoft OneNote can not sync notebooks via ethernet connection of my company. But it can sync using the Wifi. But, I do not want to fully use the Wifi because it is slow. How can I make OneNote to use the Wifi when there is ethernet connection?

Comment: But why doesn't it work over Ethernet...?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onenote-not-working-on-vpn/cedba92b-e3a7-4788-915f-9ff3949f82d1

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/OneNote/comments/bved00/onenote_hates_vpn/

Comment: The ethernet connection has security protection and it uses VPN I guess